# Define list of shapefiles in same folder (List.Vector) to use in For Loop -- Geospatial Modeling Environment

Tags: list, for-loop, geospatial, shapefile

I am trying to create a list of shapefiles in Geospatial modeling environment using list.vector. Which works and produces the following list.

```
list.vector(in="D:\Buffers", match="*.shp");
```

> D:\Buffers\OBJECTID_1.shp, 
>   D:\Buffers\OBJECTID_10.shp,
>   D:\Buffers\OBJECTID_100.shp,
>   D:\Buffers\OBJECTID_1000.shp,
>   D:\Buffers\OBJECTID_10000.shp......

I would then like to loop through the different shapefiles using the isectpolypoly function. Currently my code is:

```
list<-list.vector(in="D:\Buffers", match="*.shp");

for (i in 1:length(list)) {

isectpolypoly(in=paste(i), poly="D:\Polygons\agri.shp", field="P_", thematic=TRUE, proportion=TRUE);

};
```

I receive the following error.

> Error: The for loop has not been specified correctly. The length
>   function does not appear to refer to a defined vector.

So it appears as if I am not defining "list" correctly to be able to use it in the loop. I cannot find any clear answers on how to do this.

Can anyone help me change my code so that I can define the list of shapefiles and then loop through the shapefiles in the list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone is interested I managed to solve my own problem.

I couldn't successfully recall the list, and as each of my shapefiles had a unique number identifier, it was possible just to loop through the numbers.

```
wd<-"D:\Buffers\";
for (i in 10001:10006);
{ 
isectpolypoly(in=paste(wd,"OBJECTID_",i,".shp"),
poly="D:\Polygons\agri.shp", 
field=“CLASS”, 
prefix="P_", 
thematic=TRUE, proportion=TRUE) 
};
```